# How to create multiple files with some sample content in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to create multiple files with some sample contents in ansible.
Below is my playbook file.
    --- # create a file and copy it
    - hosts: remote
      become: yes
      remote_user: root

```
  tasks:
   - name: create multiple files
     copy:
      dest: "{{ item }}"
      content: |
         It is sample file
      with_items:
        -  Test1.txt
        -  Test2.txt
        -  Test3.txt
```

When i execute it ,i get the below error. Tried multiple ways but no luck.
How to create multiple file with some sample contents?

> fatal: [Mymachine.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an
>   option with an undefined variable.  The error was: 'item' is
>   undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in 
>   '/myshare/myuser/playbooks/multifile.yml': line 7, column 6,  but
>   may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
>   problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n
>    - name: create multiple files\n     ^ here\n"}

Answer (score 3):

`with_items` shall be in the indentation level of the [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) module:

```
tasks:
  - name: create multiple files
    copy:
      dest: "{{ item }}"
      content: |
         It is sample file
    with_items:
      - Test1.txt
      - Test2.txt
      - Test3.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html). See example below

```
tasks:
  - template:
      src: template.j2
      dest: "{{ item }}"
    loop:
      -  Test1.txt
      -  Test2.txt
      -  Test3.txt
```

.

```
# cat template.j2
It is sample file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--- # multiple files
 - hosts: all
 - user: ansible(user name)
 - become: yes
 - connection: ssh
   tasks:
     - name: list of files
       action: file name="{{item}}" state=touch
       with_items:
        - file1
        - file2
        - file3
```